# What is wrong with this binary logistic regression network that I made in pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, logistic-regression

Loss isnt decreasing and accuracy is staying at 0%. I am using the spiral dataset from "Nueral networks from scratch" by sentdex on youtube. The network I have built here is almost identical to his and I am training on the same dataset and he seemed to not have an issue training with this network. Which leads me to believe it is nothing to do with network design but a bug in my code, likely caused by the fact I am making this in pytorch and he was making it from scratch as I am new to pytorch, that I cant identify.

Here is the code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import nnfs
from nnfs.datasets import spiral_data 
nnfs.init()

X, y = spiral_data(samples=100, classes=2)
X2, y2 = spiral_data(samples=100, classes=2)

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, x, y, transform=None):

    self.n_samples = y.shape[0]
    
    x.astype('float32')
    y.astype('float32')
    self.x_data = x
    y = np.reshape(y,(-1, 1))
    self.y_data = y
    self.y_data.astype('float32')
    print(type(self.y_data[0][0]))

    self.n_features = self.x_data.shape[-1]
    self.transform = transform


    def __getitem__(self, index):
        sample = self.x_data[index], self.y_data[index]
    
        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)
    
        return sample
    
    def __len__(self):
        return self.n_samples

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_input_features, hidden_layer_size):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.n_input_features = n_input_features
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(n_input_features, hidden_layer_size)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(hidden_layer_size, 1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.initialize_weights_biases()


    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.linear1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.linear2(out)
        out = self.sigmoid(out)

        return out

    def initialize_weights_biases(self):
        for m in self.modules():
            if isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
                #m.weight.data.fill_(1.0)
                m.bias.data.fill_(0.0)

batch_size = 50
composed = transforms.Compose([ToTensor()])
train_dataset = CustomDataset(X, y, transform=composed)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)
test_dataset = CustomDataset(X2, y2, transform=composed)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)

n_features = train_dataset.n_features
learning_rate = 0.01
hidden_layer_size = 64
model = Model(n_features, hidden_layer_size)

criterion = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
num_epochs = 1000

def train(train_loader):
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0
    n_samples = train_dataset.n_samples
    n_correct = 0
    for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        labels = labels.type(torch.FloatTensor)
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        total_loss += loss
        n_correct += (outputs == labels).sum().item()

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

    acc = 100.0 * n_correct / n_samples

    return total_loss, acc

def train_1(train_loader):
    total_loss = 0
    n_samples = train_dataset.n_samples/batch_size
    n_correct = 0
    model.train()
    inputs, labels = next(iter(train_loader))
    outputs = model(inputs)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    total_loss += loss
    n_correct += (outputs == labels).sum().item()

    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    acc = 100.0 * n_correct / n_samples


    return total_loss, acc

def test(test_loader):
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        n_correct = 0
        n_samples = 0
        total_loss = 0
        for inputs, labels in test_loader:
            labels = labels.type(torch.FloatTensor)
            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            total_loss += loss
            n_samples += labels.size(0)
            n_correct += (outputs == labels).sum().item()

        acc = 100.0 * n_correct / n_samples
        return  total_loss, acc

def predict(input):
    with torch.no_grad():
        input = input.split(',')
        output = model(input)
        return output
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        training_loss, training_acc = train(train_loader)
        val_loss, val_acc =  test(test_loader)
        if (epoch+1) % 10 == 0:
            print(f'epoch: {epoch+1}, training_loss = {training_loss:.4f}')
            print(f'epoch: {epoch+1}, training_acc = {training_acc:.4f}%')
            print(f'epoch: {epoch+1}, val_loss = {val_loss:.4f}')
            print(f'epoch: {epoch+1}, val_acc = {val_acc:.4f}%')
            
    _, acc = test(test_loader)
    print(f'Accuracy on test data: {acc}%')
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'Pytorch/models/Binary_logistic_regression')
```

Here is the output:

```
`epoch: 10, training_loss = 2.7563`
`epoch: 10, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 10, val_loss = 2.7464`
`epoch: 10, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 20, training_loss = 2.7505`
`epoch: 20, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 20, val_loss = 2.7406`
`epoch: 20, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 30, training_loss = 2.7455`
`epoch: 30, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 30, val_loss = 2.7355`
`epoch: 30, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 40, training_loss = 2.7409`
`epoch: 40, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 40, val_loss = 2.7309`
`epoch: 40, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 50, training_loss = 2.7369`
`epoch: 50, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 50, val_loss = 2.7268`
`epoch: 50, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 60, training_loss = 2.7333`
`epoch: 60, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 60, val_loss = 2.7231`
`epoch: 60, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 70, training_loss = 2.7300`
`epoch: 70, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 70, val_loss = 2.7198`
`epoch: 70, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 80, training_loss = 2.7271`
`epoch: 80, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 80, val_loss = 2.7168`
`epoch: 80, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 90, training_loss = 2.7244`
`epoch: 90, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 90, val_loss = 2.7140`
`epoch: 90, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 100, training_loss = 2.7219`
`epoch: 100, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 100, val_loss = 2.7116`
`epoch: 100, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 110, training_loss = 2.7197`
`epoch: 110, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 110, val_loss = 2.7093`
`epoch: 110, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 120, training_loss = 2.7176`
`epoch: 120, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 120, val_loss = 2.7072`
`epoch: 120, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 130, training_loss = 2.7157`
`epoch: 130, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 130, val_loss = 2.7053`
`epoch: 130, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 140, training_loss = 2.7139`
`epoch: 140, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 140, val_loss = 2.7036`
`epoch: 140, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 150, training_loss = 2.7123`
`epoch: 150, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 150, val_loss = 2.7020`
`epoch: 150, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 160, training_loss = 2.7108`
`epoch: 160, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 160, val_loss = 2.7005`
`epoch: 160, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 170, training_loss = 2.7093`
`epoch: 170, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 170, val_loss = 2.6991`
`epoch: 170, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 180, training_loss = 2.7080`
`epoch: 180, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 180, val_loss = 2.6979`
`epoch: 180, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 190, training_loss = 2.7068`
`epoch: 190, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 190, val_loss = 2.6967`
`epoch: 190, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 200, training_loss = 2.7057`
`epoch: 200, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 200, val_loss = 2.6957`
`epoch: 200, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 210, training_loss = 2.7046`
`epoch: 210, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 210, val_loss = 2.6947`
`epoch: 210, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 220, training_loss = 2.7036`
`epoch: 220, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 220, val_loss = 2.6938`
`epoch: 220, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 230, training_loss = 2.7026`
`epoch: 230, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 230, val_loss = 2.6929`
`epoch: 230, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 240, training_loss = 2.7017`
`epoch: 240, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 240, val_loss = 2.6921`
`epoch: 240, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 250, training_loss = 2.7009`
`epoch: 250, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 250, val_loss = 2.6914`
`epoch: 250, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 260, training_loss = 2.7001`
`epoch: 260, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 260, val_loss = 2.6907`
`epoch: 260, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 270, training_loss = 2.6993`
`epoch: 270, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 270, val_loss = 2.6901`
`epoch: 270, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 280, training_loss = 2.6986`
`epoch: 280, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 280, val_loss = 2.6895`
`epoch: 280, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 290, training_loss = 2.6980`
`epoch: 290, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 290, val_loss = 2.6890`
`epoch: 290, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 300, training_loss = 2.6973`
`epoch: 300, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 300, val_loss = 2.6885`
`epoch: 300, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 310, training_loss = 2.6967`
`epoch: 310, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 310, val_loss = 2.6881`
`epoch: 310, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 320, training_loss = 2.6961`
`epoch: 320, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 320, val_loss = 2.6876`
`epoch: 320, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 330, training_loss = 2.6956`
`epoch: 330, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 330, val_loss = 2.6872`
`epoch: 330, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 340, training_loss = 2.6950`
`epoch: 340, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 340, val_loss = 2.6869`
`epoch: 340, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 350, training_loss = 2.6945`
`epoch: 350, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 350, val_loss = 2.6865`
`epoch: 350, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 360, training_loss = 2.6940`
`epoch: 360, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 360, val_loss = 2.6862`
`epoch: 360, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 370, training_loss = 2.6936`
`epoch: 370, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 370, val_loss = 2.6859`
`epoch: 370, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 380, training_loss = 2.6931`
`epoch: 380, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 380, val_loss = 2.6856`
`epoch: 380, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 390, training_loss = 2.6927`
`epoch: 390, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 390, val_loss = 2.6854`
`epoch: 390, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 400, training_loss = 2.6923`
`epoch: 400, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 400, val_loss = 2.6851`
`epoch: 400, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 410, training_loss = 2.6918`
`epoch: 410, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 410, val_loss = 2.6849`
`epoch: 410, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 420, training_loss = 2.6914`
`epoch: 420, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 420, val_loss = 2.6847`
`epoch: 420, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 430, training_loss = 2.6910`
`epoch: 430, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 430, val_loss = 2.6845`
`epoch: 430, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 440, training_loss = 2.6907`
`epoch: 440, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 440, val_loss = 2.6843`
`epoch: 440, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 450, training_loss = 2.6903`
`epoch: 450, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 450, val_loss = 2.6841`
`epoch: 450, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 460, training_loss = 2.6900`
`epoch: 460, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 460, val_loss = 2.6839`
`epoch: 460, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 470, training_loss = 2.6896`
`epoch: 470, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 470, val_loss = 2.6838`
`epoch: 470, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 480, training_loss = 2.6893`
`epoch: 480, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 480, val_loss = 2.6836`
`epoch: 480, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 490, training_loss = 2.6889`
`epoch: 490, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 490, val_loss = 2.6834`
`epoch: 490, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 500, training_loss = 2.6886`
`epoch: 500, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 500, val_loss = 2.6833`
`epoch: 500, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 510, training_loss = 2.6883`
`epoch: 510, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 510, val_loss = 2.6831`
`epoch: 510, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 520, training_loss = 2.6880`
`epoch: 520, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 520, val_loss = 2.6830`
`epoch: 520, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 530, training_loss = 2.6877`
`epoch: 530, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 530, val_loss = 2.6829`
`epoch: 530, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 540, training_loss = 2.6874`
`epoch: 540, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 540, val_loss = 2.6827`
`epoch: 540, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 550, training_loss = 2.6871`
`epoch: 550, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 550, val_loss = 2.6826`
`epoch: 550, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 560, training_loss = 2.6868`
`epoch: 560, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 560, val_loss = 2.6825`
`epoch: 560, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 570, training_loss = 2.6865`
`epoch: 570, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 570, val_loss = 2.6824`
`epoch: 570, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 580, training_loss = 2.6862`
`epoch: 580, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 580, val_loss = 2.6822`
`epoch: 580, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 590, training_loss = 2.6859`
`epoch: 590, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 590, val_loss = 2.6821`
`epoch: 590, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 600, training_loss = 2.6856`
`epoch: 600, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 600, val_loss = 2.6820`
`epoch: 600, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 610, training_loss = 2.6854`
`epoch: 610, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 610, val_loss = 2.6819`
`epoch: 610, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 620, training_loss = 2.6851`
`epoch: 620, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 620, val_loss = 2.6818`
`epoch: 620, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 630, training_loss = 2.6848`
`epoch: 630, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 630, val_loss = 2.6817`
`epoch: 630, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 640, training_loss = 2.6845`
`epoch: 640, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 640, val_loss = 2.6816`
`epoch: 640, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 650, training_loss = 2.6843`
`epoch: 650, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 650, val_loss = 2.6815`
`epoch: 650, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 660, training_loss = 2.6840`
`epoch: 660, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 660, val_loss = 2.6815`
`epoch: 660, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 670, training_loss = 2.6838`
`epoch: 670, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 670, val_loss = 2.6814`
`epoch: 670, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 680, training_loss = 2.6835`
`epoch: 680, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 680, val_loss = 2.6813`
`epoch: 680, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 690, training_loss = 2.6832`
`epoch: 690, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 690, val_loss = 2.6812`
`epoch: 690, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 700, training_loss = 2.6830`
`epoch: 700, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 700, val_loss = 2.6812`
`epoch: 700, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 710, training_loss = 2.6827`
`epoch: 710, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 710, val_loss = 2.6811`
`epoch: 710, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 720, training_loss = 2.6825`
`epoch: 720, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 720, val_loss = 2.6810`
`epoch: 720, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 730, training_loss = 2.6823`
`epoch: 730, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 730, val_loss = 2.6809`
`epoch: 730, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 740, training_loss = 2.6820`
`epoch: 740, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 740, val_loss = 2.6809`
`epoch: 740, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 750, training_loss = 2.6818`
`epoch: 750, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 750, val_loss = 2.6808`
`epoch: 750, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 760, training_loss = 2.6816`
`epoch: 760, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 760, val_loss = 2.6808`
`epoch: 760, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 770, training_loss = 2.6813`
`epoch: 770, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 770, val_loss = 2.6807`
`epoch: 770, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 780, training_loss = 2.6811`
`epoch: 780, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 780, val_loss = 2.6806`
`epoch: 780, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 790, training_loss = 2.6809`
`epoch: 790, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 790, val_loss = 2.6806`
`epoch: 790, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 800, training_loss = 2.6807`
`epoch: 800, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 800, val_loss = 2.6805`
`epoch: 800, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 810, training_loss = 2.6804`
`epoch: 810, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 810, val_loss = 2.6805`
`epoch: 810, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 820, training_loss = 2.6802`
`epoch: 820, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 820, val_loss = 2.6804`
`epoch: 820, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 830, training_loss = 2.6800`
`epoch: 830, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 830, val_loss = 2.6804`
`epoch: 830, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 840, training_loss = 2.6798`
`epoch: 840, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 840, val_loss = 2.6803`
`epoch: 840, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 850, training_loss = 2.6796`
`epoch: 850, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 850, val_loss = 2.6803`
`epoch: 850, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 860, training_loss = 2.6794`
`epoch: 860, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 860, val_loss = 2.6803`
`epoch: 860, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 870, training_loss = 2.6792`
`epoch: 870, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 870, val_loss = 2.6802`
`epoch: 870, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 880, training_loss = 2.6790`
`epoch: 880, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 880, val_loss = 2.6802`
`epoch: 880, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 890, training_loss = 2.6787`
`epoch: 890, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 890, val_loss = 2.6801`
`epoch: 890, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 900, training_loss = 2.6785`
`epoch: 900, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 900, val_loss = 2.6801`
`epoch: 900, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 910, training_loss = 2.6783`
`epoch: 910, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 910, val_loss = 2.6800`
`epoch: 910, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 920, training_loss = 2.6781`
`epoch: 920, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 920, val_loss = 2.6800`
`epoch: 920, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 930, training_loss = 2.6779`
`epoch: 930, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 930, val_loss = 2.6800`
`epoch: 930, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 940, training_loss = 2.6777`
`epoch: 940, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 940, val_loss = 2.6799`
`epoch: 940, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 950, training_loss = 2.6775`
`epoch: 950, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 950, val_loss = 2.6799`
`epoch: 950, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 960, training_loss = 2.6773`
`epoch: 960, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 960, val_loss = 2.6799`
`epoch: 960, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 970, training_loss = 2.6771`
`epoch: 970, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 970, val_loss = 2.6799`
`epoch: 970, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 980, training_loss = 2.6769`
`epoch: 980, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 980, val_loss = 2.6798`
`epoch: 980, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 990, training_loss = 2.6767`
`epoch: 990, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 990, val_loss = 2.6798`
`epoch: 990, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 1000, training_loss = 2.6765`
`epoch: 1000, training_acc = 0.0000%`
`epoch: 1000, val_loss = 2.6798`
`epoch: 1000, val_acc = 0.0000%`
`Accuracy on test data: 0.0%`
```

Here is his output from his network made from scratch:

```
epoch: 0, acc: 0.500, loss: 0.693 (data_loss: 0.693, reg_loss: 0.000), lr: 0.001
epoch: 100, acc: 0.630, loss: 0.674 (data_loss: 0.673, reg_loss: 0.001), lr: 0.0009999505024501287
epoch: 200, acc: 0.625, loss: 0.669 (data_loss: 0.668, reg_loss: 0.001), lr: 0.0009999005098992651
epoch: 300, acc: 0.650, loss: 0.664 (data_loss: 0.663, reg_loss: 0.002), lr: 0.000999850522346909
epoch: 400, acc: 0.650, loss: 0.659 (data_loss: 0.657, reg_loss: 0.002), lr: 0.0009998005397923115
epoch: 500, acc: 0.675, loss: 0.647 (data_loss: 0.644, reg_loss: 0.004), lr: 0.0009997505622347225
epoch: 600, acc: 0.720, loss: 0.632 (data_loss: 0.625, reg_loss: 0.006), lr: 0.0009997005896733929
epoch: 1500, acc: 0.805, loss: 0.503 (data_loss: 0.464, reg_loss: 0.039), lr: 0.0009992510613295335
epoch: 2500, acc: 0.855, loss: 0.430 (data_loss: 0.379, reg_loss: 0.052), lr: 0.0009987520593019025`
epoch: 4500, acc: 0.910, loss: 0.346 (data_loss: 0.285, reg_loss: 0.061), lr: 0.0009977555488927658
epoch: 4600, acc: 0.905, loss: 0.340 (data_loss: 0.278, reg_loss: 0.062), lr: 0.000997705775569079
epoch: 4700, acc: 0.910, loss: 0.330 (data_loss: 0.268, reg_loss: 0.062), lr: 0.0009976560072110577
epoch: 4800, acc: 0.920, loss: 0.326 (data_loss: 0.263, reg_loss: 0.063), lr: 0.0009976062438179587
epoch: 6100, acc: 0.940, loss: 0.291 (data_loss: 0.223, reg_loss: 0.069), lr: 0.0009969597711777935
epoch: 6600, acc: 0.950, loss: 0.279 (data_loss: 0.211, reg_loss: 0.068), lr: 0.000996711350897713
epoch: 6700, acc: 0.955, loss: 0.272 (data_loss: 0.203, reg_loss: 0.069), lr: 0.0009966616816971556
epoch: 6800, acc: 0.955, loss: 0.269 (data_loss: 0.200, reg_loss: 0.069), lr: 0.00099661201744669
epoch: 6900, acc: 0.960, loss: 0.266 (data_loss: 0.197, reg_loss: 0.069), lr: 0.0009965623581455767
epoch: 9800, acc: 0.965, loss: 0.222 (data_loss: 0.158, reg_loss: 0.063), lr: 0.0009951243880606966
epoch: 9900, acc: 0.965, loss: 0.221 (data_loss: 0.157, reg_loss: 0.063), lr: 0.0009950748768967994
epoch: 10000, acc: 0.965, loss: 0.219 (data_loss: 0.156, reg_loss: 0.063), lr: 0.0009950253706593885
validation, acc: 0.945, loss: 0.207
```

Comment: It looks like the accuracy is computed incorrectly. Here's a simple debugging technique: 1) Get one pair of `(inputs, labels)` from your data loader. 2) Run the model: `outputs = model(inputs)`. 3) Do the `outputs` make sense? Are they of the same type as `labels`? Are they of the same shape as `labels`? Are they in the same range as `labels`? (e.g. `outputs` could be reals from -5 to 6, while `labels` could be binary 0 or 1). Are they expected to be literally exactly equal, or can they be equal within a tolerance?

Comment: Hint: The output of a `BCELoss` trained model can be interpreted as the probability (or model confidence) that label == 1.